# How to replace Remove, Add and Replace Panes?

Tags: java, javafx

JAVA's abstraction is somehow brought out by allowing us to create a JFrame *(and save it in its own **.JAVA file**)* and populate it with different kinds of objects such as JPanels, JTextFields ... *(saved in different files)* if and when needed by using the     remove(),   add(),  validate(),     repaint() methods.

I'm trying to move my JAVA project to JAVA-FX due its great flexibility in design via JavaFX Scene Builder and css. Are there any equivalents to the above methods here (In JAVA-FX)? Is there a way I could create a Pane or a Label ... and save it in its own file as it waits to replace onother Pane with its own child Nodes ***(and saved in its own file)*** on the Stage later when it's called via an action, such as a button click?

Would really appreciate any help. Sample code enumerating the above could help also.

Thank you all in advance.

*Your's trully, Complete JAVA-FX **Newbie**.*

Comment: You should almost never need to call `validate()` or `repaint()`...

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd revert most of my edit?

Comment: Also: why not just add all the controls you'll need in a panel up front, and set the ones you don't need to be invisible? That's very often a better idea than fiddling with the component tree at runtime.

Comment: I think what happened is that I tried to edit a word after I published the Question almost immediately after I published. I think we were trying to save the our own edits at the same time. I was not reverting any of your edit.

Comment: Fair enough I guess. CBA to reconcile them, but mind that capitalising "JAVA" tends to drive people (like me) up walls, and salutations and professing newbiedom are mostly clutter.

Comment: Won't this affect memory in a bad way If I end up with so many hidden items that might not be used even once. I thought it would be much better to load only the items I thought would be used and load others on request.

Comment: Premature optimisation, root of all evil and all that. Don't make up problems you don't actually have, focus on the problems you do. Computers have obscene amounts of memory these days. The bitmap that contains your app's rendered UI probably takes up several times more memory than your app's component tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular JavaFX application, there is only one **primary stage** and its one **scene**. Create your FXML file (optionally with its controller) containing any JavaFX node and load this file on button action using `FXMLoader`. Then you can use the loaded node as a root of scene;
`scene.setRoot(MYNode)` (though only `Parent` can be set as root)
or add it to subtree of root node as a child;
if you know the substructure: `scene.getRoot().getChildren().get(3).getChildren().add(MYNode);`
if you know the **`id`**: `scene.lookup("myPane").getChildren().add(MYNode);`

The same logic applies to another FXML file(s) being loaded in another action event.