# Changing Panes in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I've been trying to interchange Panes by setting the visbility status to true or false as shown below, but noyhing's working so far.

**My failing approach so far:**
*The program starts with the visibility of homeContentDisplay set to true. Clicking on a button sets it to false as the visibility of page2ContentDisplay is changed to to true.*

**The Code:**

```
@FXML
private Pane homeContentDisplay;
private Pane page2ContentDisplay;

@FXML
private void handleButtonActionShow(MouseEvent event) {
    homeContentDisplay.setVisible(false);
    page2ContentDisplay.setVisible(true);

    FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(
            Duration.millis(3000), homeContentDisplay
            );

    fadeIn.setFromValue(0.0);
    fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);
    fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);
    fadeIn.setAutoReverse(false);

    fadeIn.play();
}
```

1. What am I doing wrong in my Code?
2. Is there a better way of going on about this, that is changing Panes?

Comment: Please also include your fxml file.

Comment: Why `page2ContentDisplay` is not annotated with `@FXML` ?

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses.  [tarrsalah](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1120221/tarrsalah), you are right. It's the @FXML. Wish I could up-vote you, but I can't; my points aren't high enough. Will do when they add up.

Comment: Is there a better way of going about this? I don't like working by setting visibility- true/false. This was my earlier question:  [How to replace Remove, Add and Replace Panes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853265/how-to-replace-remove-add-and-replace-panes#comment27818249_18853265)